# How do you calculate a running column minimum using tidyverse functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have dataframe with two columns, type and val. I'd like calculate a grouped (grouped by type) running column minimum using tidyverse function.  I attempted this using dplyr and map function, but I'm not getting the output that I was targeting.  Here is a reproducible example that contains my actual and desired output.  Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)


df <- tibble(type=c('m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f'),val=c(23,24,22,23,20,19,20,21,18,22,10,11,12,9,9,10,7,7,6,4))

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(run_min = map(val,~min(.,val))) %>% 
  unnest()

## OUTPUT THAT IM GETTING

print(df, n=20)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#> # Groups:   type [2]
#>    type    val run_min
#>    <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 m        23      18
#>  2 m        24      18
#>  3 m        22      18
#>  4 m        23      18
#>  5 m        20      18
#>  6 m        19      18
#>  7 m        20      18
#>  8 m        21      18
#>  9 m        18      18
#> 10 m        22      18
#> 11 f        10       4
#> 12 f        11       4
#> 13 f        12       4
#> 14 f         9       4
#> 15 f         9       4
#> 16 f        10       4
#> 17 f         7       4
#> 18 f         7       4
#> 19 f         6       4
#> 20 f         4       4


## WANT THIS OUTPUT

## # A tibble: 20 x 3
## # Groups:   type [2]
##    type    val run_min
##    <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
##  1 m        23      23
##  2 m        24      23
##  3 m        22      22
##  4 m        23      22
##  5 m        20      20
##  6 m        19      19
##  7 m        20      19
##  8 m        21      19
##  9 m        18      18
## 10 m        22      18
## 11 f        10      10
## 12 f        11      10
## 13 f        12      10
## 14 f         9       9
## 15 f         9       9
## 16 f        10       9
## 17 f         7       7
## 18 f         7       7
## 19 f         6       6
## 20 f         4       4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use `cummin`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(run_min = cummin(val)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   type    val run_min
   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 m        23      23
 2 m        24      23
 3 m        22      22
 4 m        23      22
 5 m        20      20
 6 m        19      19
 7 m        20      19
 8 m        21      19
 9 m        18      18
10 m        22      18
11 f        10      10
12 f        11      10
13 f        12      10
14 f         9       9
15 f         9       9
16 f        10       9
17 f         7       7
18 f         7       7
19 f         6       6
20 f         4       4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking specifically for a `tidyverse` solution, then one `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(type) %>%
 mutate(run_min = accumulate(val, ~ ifelse(.x < .y, .x, .y)))

  type    val run_min
   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 m        23      23
 2 m        24      23
 3 m        22      22
 4 m        23      22
 5 m        20      20
 6 m        19      19
 7 m        20      19
 8 m        21      19
 9 m        18      18
10 m        22      18
11 f        10      10
12 f        11      10
13 f        12      10
14 f         9       9
15 f         9       9
16 f        10       9
17 f         7       7
18 f         7       7
19 f         6       6
20 f         4       4
```

Otherwise, you can simply use `cummin()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(type) %>%
 mutate(run_min = cummin(val))
```